# Compile error in license Plate Dataset Generator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm trying to compile a Plate Dataset Generator in python 3 but it doesn't compile well, I was thinking that it may be a syntax problem between versions of the required libraries.

I leave the link below https://github.com/tomcastro/licensePlateDatasetGenerator

The program leaves this error:

```
command: py -3 randomPlateGenerator.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "randomPlateGenerator.py", line 76, in <module>
    randomPlateGenerator(style=style, reps=reps)
  File "randomPlateGenerator.py", line 59, in randomPlateGenerator
    numberToImage(licensePlate, style)
  File "C:\Users\X\Desktop\licensePlateDatasetGenerator-master\licensePlateDatasetGenerator-master\numberToImage.py", line 48, in numberToImage
    text += getBoundingBoxes(canvas_cp, lp, xoffset=20, yoffset=20)
  File "C:\Users\X\Desktop\licensePlateDatasetGenerator-master\licensePlateDatasetGenerator-master\numberToImage.py", line 88, in getBoundingBoxes
    im2, cnts, h = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

By last, the file named randomPlateGenerator.py at line 1 have to change `# coding: utf8` to `#coding: utf-8`.

Any help is really welcome

Comment: check output of `cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)`

Comment: already did it but could found nothing

Comment: that function is giving 2 values and you are expecting 3 , i think issue is there

Comment: @prashantrana yep, thresh is a variable and the other 2 parameters are numbers.  so when I try to see well and follow the variables to find the problem, I don't detect nothing:/

Comment: i mean here ` im2, cnts, h` this part is problem , you are expecting 3 vlaues , but you are getting 2